# Why are $S$, $Z$ and $M$ used to denote the Conductor, Cyclic subspace and Annihilator in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In the text *Linear Algebra* (by Hoffman and Kunze), there are notations S, Z, M. What are these short for – that is, why are these particular three letters used for the following concepts?

> **(i) S**. Let $W$ be an invariant subspace for $T$ and let $\alpha$ be a vector in $V$. The $T$- conductor of $\alpha$ into $W$ is the set $S_{T}(\alpha ; W)$, which consists of all polynomials $g$ (over the scalar field) such that $g(T)\alpha$ is in $W$.
>
> **(ii) Z**. If $\alpha$ is any vector in $V$, the $T$- cyclic subspace generated by $\alpha$ is the subspace $Z(\alpha ;T)$ of all vectors of the form $g(T)\alpha$, $g$ in $F[x]$.
>
> **(iii) M**. If  $\alpha$ is any vector in $V$, the $T$-annihilator of $\alpha$ is the ideal $M(\alpha ; T)$ in $F[x]$ consisting of all polynomials $g$ over $F$ such that $g(T)\alpha = 0$.

Comment: He seems to define each notation right after he uses it.

Comment: @MarkFantini I think asker is asking why *these* letters; eg we could use any letter for the set of integers but we use $\mathbb{Z}$ from the German *Zahlen* etc

Comment: For $Z(\alpha;T)$, it certainly comes *Zyklische UnterModuln*.

Comment: My guess for the $T$-conductor is that becuase it is also called the 'stuffer' (*das einstopfende Ideal*), as the authors mention on page 201 (2nd edition), the letter $S$ is used to denote it.

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments above.*

---

The $T$-conductor of $\alpha$ into $W$ is denoted by the letter **S** possibly because the $T$-conductor is also called the "stuffer" (*das einstopfende Ideal*), as the authors mention on page 201 (2nd edition).

The $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $\alpha$ is denoted by the letter **Z** possibly because it is also called *Zyklische UnterModuln* in German, as mentioned by @Bernard in the comments above.